# Float number from one IBAction to another swift

Tags: swift

I have searched everywhere and can't seem to find an answer anywhere. I'm new to using Swift on Xcode, and before I would use Objective-C. On objective-c I could get a number in one IBAction, and put it as a float, and use it again in anither IBAction.

like

```
Float number

-(IBAction)winch
{
  number=1;
}
-(IBAction)fuel
{
  number=2;
}  
-(IBAction)tire
{
  number=3;
}
-(IBAction)tow
{
  number=4;
}
-(IBAction)jump
{
  number=5;
}
-(IBAction)battery
{
  number=6;
}
-(IBAction)unlock
{
  number=7;
}
-(IBAction)show
{
  numberField.text=(@"@f",number)
{
```

is there any way to do this same thing in Swift?

Comment: Just do the exact same thing as you did in Objective-C? Only difference is spelling; i.e. the property is now spelled `var number: Float = 0`

Comment: It seems like you haven't tried very hard to convert your code to Swift. You should read Apple's `UIButton` documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var number = 0

@IBAction func winch (_ sender:Any) {
    number = 1
}

@IBAction func fuel (_ sender:Any) {
    number = 2
}

@IBAction func tire (_ sender:Any) {
    number = 3
}   

@IBAction func tow (_ sender:Any) {
    number = 4
}

@IBAction func jump (_ sender:Any) {
    number = 5
}

@IBAction func battery (_ sender:Any) {
    number = 6
}

@IBAction func unlock (_ sender:Any) {
    number = 7
}

func show () {
    numberField.text = "\(number)"
}
```

Comment: This won’t compile because of `let number...`

Comment: Since there is no use of `sender` in the original Objective-C code, there is no need to add the `sender` parameter to the Swift code.